# Dynamically retrieving custom list data and displaying on a web-form

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, custom-actions

I need to implement a solution that retrieves data from a custom list and display on a web-form. This data would be a mixture of picture and text columns. The user is then allowed to select multiple rows using check-box, the items that user wants to purchase. And clicking on save updates the list. Please make a note I need to display the columns in row wise similar to how they are displayed in custom list. I need your advice how should I implement this solution, what tools and technology I should opt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are comfortable with C# or VB.NET and your farm administrators allow the deployment of wsp based features, I would suggest opting for a custom web part.

You can choose either a visual web part or the traditional web part. The following link should get you started (note: this is for the visual web part): http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Roji.Joy/creating-web-parts-for-sharepoint-2010-using-visual-studio-2010/

You could also opt for using the javascript version of the client object model: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh372944%28v=office.14%29.aspx

There are many variations on the above options (including custom application pages, traditional ASP.NET web application using the client object model, etc.) but the first two are good choices if you want to stick to C# or only HTML/CSS/JS.

As for the look and feel, you should take a look at the CSS classes being used on your SharePoint instance and mark your HTML with those classes (e.g. make the grid look like a SharePoint list, etc.).

P.S.: You may hear about sandboxed solutions, but I'd stay away from them since they are no longer supported in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Thanks Jared for your answer, I have developed the application using custom web-part and it is working fine as I expected.